# Can I transform our existing project to MVVM?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a large existing project in Silverlight which has many user controls with code behind files for complicated business logic. I don't know if I can still migrate my code to the MVVM pattern (I'm pretty new to this pattern). What I mean is that if it is easy to migrate the existing code or I must rewrite everything to fulfill this MVVM requirement?

Also, it seems the business application template is a type of MVVM. Is this the most popular template I should use? Is there any online tutorial to learn this template?

Many thanks,

Wei

Comment: This question is way too broad to be answered in its current state.

Comment: Can you point out what concept I get confused or what detail I should provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rarely recommend migrating existing code to fit a new design pattern.  This is really only cost effective if the project is fairly small and you're migrating in preparation for making a very large number of changes (which will then benefit from the 'improved' pattern.)  Note, also, that the productivity benefits of a pattern like MVVM are somewhat delayed (there is a lot of time spent learning the pattern, so you need to be able to tolerate increased costs and delays in the short term.)  If I were in your shoes, I'd practice MVVM on new projects or on reasonably well-isolated add-on features for your application.  Either that or work on some personal side projects; a Frankenstein software re-architecture project is a maintenance engineer's worst nightmare.